# Can't connect to this network - better diagnosis?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I can't connect to my wifi anymore. It used to work, now it doesn't. I have a TP-Link Archer T9E wireless card. I can't really try to connect to other networks as it is not a laptop. The only thing I can do is setting my phone as hotspot, and this works. I've tried disable/reenabling the wireless card, forgetting the network, restarting the router, and reinstalling the card's driver. None of this worked. I've seen several people with similar problems, I've tried everything I could find, nothing worked. Is there a way to get a better diagnosis? Like why it can't connect to the network, at which phase it fails, or something? Thanks.

Comment: What else has changed?  System update?  Driver update?  What have you tried?  What is everything?  I never could get the T9E to work with Windows 10 and it was known problem that TP-Link would not recognize, I'm not sure if that situation has changed in the last 9 months.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths nothing has changed. I wasn’t home for a week, came back to this. That’s the weird part really. It used to work, now it doesn’t. My phone can still connect though. My computer did connect for a few hours this evening and then refused again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue several times.  What fixed it for me was a series of command-line interface networking commands followed by a reboot.  Give 'em a try, you've got nothing to lose!

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log hit.
```

I also entered the following commands, but I don't believe they did anything:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

... the Dell tech who helped me fix this the first time it happened used them.  This command does do something, though:

```
netsh /flushdns
```

Now reboot the machine and it should connect to your Wi-Fi without any problem.  Worked for me at least four times (until now, anyway... tried to install Windows Subsystem for Linux, rebooted, and now I've got the old "can't connect to this network" thing again, and none of these commands helps.  Restoring to an earlier restore point didn't help, nor did removing the subsystem.

Comment: Some formatting would make this answer much easier to read. Use line breaks and the options in the WYSIWYG editor to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 3 years late, but I've got a fix. First you have to download the driver mentioned in this page: https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/204498?fbclid=IwAR33oT9VjdsGEZZTkgs0uR07bbmCbQy4IeVWQ-Rm_crY3W9_7QVYSClKk8g

Especifically: https://static.tp-link.com/2019/201911/20191129/Archer T6E T9E_ASUS driver_7.35.351.0.zip

Then you have to install it using this instructions: https://www.tp-link.com/support/faq/2722/

After that, remove the middle antenna, you have to leave only the edge antennas. If your problem was similar to mine, then you'll be able to connect to your wifi again.